# How to identify source of new javascript error in stale Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

Trying to 'thaw' a year-old project and seeing some strange javascript errors. I haven't had much luck searching for solution.

I'm guessing it has something to do with something on my dev box being too recent (or too old) to work with this codebase but not sure best way to troubleshoot that.

Any thoughts how to tackle this?

Thanks for any help!

Here's the spec:

```
  # ./spec/support/helpers/comments_page_helpers
  ...
  def open_image_comments_modal(section_position:, photo_position:)
    selector = "editable-section:nth-child(#{section_position}) " \
      "li.photo:nth-child(#{photo_position})"

    within selector do
      find('a.image-wrapper img').click        ### <== line #23
    end

    expect(page).to have_css('.modal-comments-container')
  end
  ...
```

and the failure:

```
5) Comment creation for image behaves like added comment adds single comment
     Failure/Error: find('a.image-wrapper img').click

     Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
       One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

       Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"message":"unauthorized"},"status":401,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api/v1/comments","params":{"commentable_id":4179,"commentable_type":"Attachment"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json"}},"statusText":"Unauthorized "}
       Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"message":"unauthorized"},"status":401,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api/v1/comments","params":{"commentable_id":4179,"commentable_type":"Attachment"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json"}},"statusText":"Unauthorized "}
           at http://127.0.0.1:50066/assets/application-f59647de5de8bec0c768ec8da4dfa097f8e2db01844d3e5d71b6a6dd8b15abfb.js:26422
     Shared Example Group: "added comment" called from ./spec/features/comments/creation_spec.rb:76
     # ./spec/support/helpers/comments_page_helpers.rb:23:in `block in open_image_comments_modal'
     # ./spec/support/helpers/comments_page_helpers.rb:22:in `open_image_comments_modal'
     # ./spec/features/comments/creation_spec.rb:69:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: The JS error tells you what the issue is - you're not authorized to access whatever is at `/api/v1/comments`  -  Is that from a request back to your own app? or is it from a request to an outside service?  Also you're using Poltergeist which is basically equivalent to 6-7 year old version of Safari at this point.  You're going to better off using headless Chrome or Firefox through the selenium driver if you're doing anything modern with JS/CSS

Comment: request for `/api/v1/comments` is a callback to our own app. not sure why it wouldn't be responding when app is running during test?  The app has been in 'hibernation' for a year. I've been asked to 'thaw' it. I'd like to get old test, that used to pass, working before migrating to chromedriver. Looking for best way to approach this.

Comment: It is responding - with a 401 - not authorized error -- check your rails test.log to see why the request is being denied.